# How to change top image once every time user scrolls back to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im creating a website and one of the function is to change the display image in the section every time user scrolls back to that section

I've tried using the carousel method whereby image changes once when scroll value reaches (lets say) 100. The website glitches and image change multiple times

As shown, code should cause image to change only when user scroll pass a certain point. However, when user scroll pass a certain point, image changes multiple times and starts lagging.

```js
var slideTopIndex = 0;
showTopDivs(slideTopIndex);

function plusTopDivs(n) {
  showTopDivs(slideTopIndex += n);
}

function currentTopDiv(n) {
  showTopDivs(slideTopIndex = n);
}

function showTopDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myTopSlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dotted");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideTopIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideTopIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  x[slideTopIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideTopIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

showTopSlides();

function showTopSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("myTopSlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dotted");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideTopIndex++;
  if (slideTopIndex > slides.length) {
    slideTopIndex = 1
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideTopIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideTopIndex - 1].className += " active";

  window.onscroll = function() {

    if (window.pageYOffset = 500) {
      setTimeout(showTopSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
    }
  }


}
```

```html
<div class="myTopSlides fade">
  <div class=" vidsection">



    <div class=" video1"></div>
    <div class="zt-content zt-center zt-display-center" style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4); max-width:30%; height:auto; padding:48px;z-index: 2;">The platform that bridges today to tomorrow's learning landscape</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Slide 2 -->

<div class="myTopSlides fade">
  <div class=" vidsection">


    <div class=" video2"></div>

    <div class="zt-content zt-center zt-display-center" style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4); max-width:30%; height:auto; padding:48px;z-index: 2;">The platform that bridges today to tomorrow's learning landscape</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Slide 3 -->

<div class="myTopSlides fade">
  <div class=" vidsection">

    <div class=" video3"></div>
    <div class="zt-content zt-center zt-display-center" style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4); max-width:30%; height:auto; padding:48px; z-index: 2;">The platform that bridges today to tomorrow's learning landscape</div>
  </div>
</div>


<br>

<div style="display:none;">
  <span class="dotted" onclick="currentTopDiv(1)"></span>
  <span class="dotted" onclick="currentTopDiv(2)"></span>
  <span class="dotted" onclick="currentTopDiv(3)"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the problem is the `setTimeout()` function, have you tried to remove it?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it run as you expect

Comment: Yes i have tried removing the setTimeout() function. When removed, the image doesnt change anymore.